# Can't access the http server in VPS

Tags: http, server, vps

I have server on digitalocean. There was running nginx. I killed all nginx processes and created simple node.js http server:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log('requeeeeest');
    res.end('hello world');
}).listen(80, '0.0.0.0', () => { console.log('listening'); });
```

But when I run my server, I cannot connect to it. My request is
perennially waiting. Also to whatever port I try to connect - there is perennial request waiting. Why ports are "running"? And why I cannot connect to my node.js server. By the way, my server is accessible from localhost.

Comment: You need to use sudo for node to be able to bind port 80.

Comment: sudo doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the firewall was running.